# SwiftUI - Limit drag to rectangle bounds of an Image after being scaled

Tags: swiftui

I would like to limit the drag area to the specific bounds of an image. The image itself could have different aspect ratios, or the phone could be in portrait or in landscape mode. I've tried different solutions found on SO, but I couldn't resolve my issue...

For some reason I cannot get the correct CGRect origin point of the scaled image. And my drag indicator either can't be dragged in certain areas of the image, or it can cross the boundaries of the image.

[image]

This is the view I am trying to drag and drop on top of an image.

```
import SwiftUI

struct EVPointView: View {
    var id = UUID()
    var location: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50)
    
    var body: some View {
        Capsule(style: .continuous)
            .stroke(.regularMaterial, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2))
            .background(Capsule().fill(.ultraThinMaterial))
            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
    }
}

struct EVPointView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        EVPointView()
    }
}
```

This is the view that contains the image:

```
import SwiftUI

extension View {
    func readRect(onChange: @escaping (CGRect) -> Void) -> some View {
        background(
            GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
                Color.clear
                    .preference(key: BoundsPreferenceKey.self, value: geometryProxy.frame(in: .global))
            }
        )
        .onPreferenceChange(BoundsPreferenceKey.self, perform: onChange)
    }
}

struct BoundsPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGRect = .zero
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let photo: UIImage = UIImage(named: "BeachPan")!
    @State private var evPointLocation: CGPoint = CGPoint()
    @State private var imageFrame = CGRect()
    
    var body: some View {
        return VStack(spacing: 0) {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                ZStack {
                    Image(uiImage: photo)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .readRect(onChange: { imageRect in
                            imageFrame = imageRect
                        })
                        .border(.red)
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
                        .background(.black)
                    HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 50) {
                        Text("EV Location x: \(Int(evPointLocation.x)) y: \(Int(evPointLocation.y))")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .background(Color.black)
                            .padding(.top, 20)
                        VStack {
                            Text("Image Frame: width: \(Int(imageFrame.width)) - height: \(Int(imageFrame.height))")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .background(Color.black)
                            Text("Origin: x \(Int(imageFrame.origin.x)) - y \(Int(imageFrame.origin.y))")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .background(Color.black)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    EVPointView()
                        .position(evPointLocation)
                        .gesture(DragGesture()
                            .onChanged { value in
                                let rect = CGRect(origin: imageFrame.origin, size: CGSize(width: imageFrame.width, height: imageFrame.height))
                                if rect.contains(value.location) {
                                    self.evPointLocation = value.location
                                }
                            })
                        .onAppear {
                            evPointLocation = CGPoint(x: imageFrame.origin.x + 20, y: imageFrame.origin.y + 20)
                        }
                } //: ZStack
            } //: Geo
        } //: VStack
    }
    
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .previewInterfaceOrientation(.landscapeLeft)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whoever faces the same problem, I've solved the problem with the below code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let photo: UIImage = UIImage(named: "beach")!
    @State private var evPointLocation: CGPoint = CGPoint()
    @State private var imageFrame = CGRect()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            GeometryReader { viewGeo in
                GeometryReader { imgGeo in
                    ZStack {
                        Image(uiImage: photo)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .onReceive(Just(imgGeo), perform: { _ in
                                let localFrame = imgGeo.frame(in: .local)
                                imageFrame = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: photo.size, insideRect: localFrame)
                            })
                        EVPointView()
                            .position(evPointLocation)
                            .gesture(DragGesture()
                                .onChanged { value in
                                    if imageFrame.contains(value.location) {
                                        self.evPointLocation = value.location
                                    }
                                })
                            .onAppear {
                                evPointLocation = CGPoint(x: imageFrame.origin.x + 50, y: imageFrame.origin.y + 50)
                            }
                    } //: ZStack
                } //: imgGeo
                .frame(width: viewGeo.size.width * 0.8, height: viewGeo.size.height * 0.8)
                .background(.black)
            } //: viewGeo
        } //: VStack
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a matter of difference in global and local coordinate space. Here is a version using an own named coordinate space, that works.
Unfortunately your `readRect()` method doesn't support coordinate spaces, so I replaced it with a simple GeometryReader background on the image.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let photo: UIImage = UIImage(named: "beach")!
    @State private var evPointLocation: CGPoint = CGPoint()
    @State private var imageFrame = CGRect()
    
    var body: some View {
        // no VStack, GeometryReader necessary
        ZStack {
            Image(uiImage: photo)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                // the following is a simple version of your imageRect
                .background( GeometryReader { geo in Color.clear.onAppear {
                    imageFrame = geo.frame(in: .named("myCoord")) // HERE YOU GET POS IN YOUR COORD SPACE
                    evPointLocation = CGPoint(x: imageFrame.origin.x + 30, y: imageFrame.origin.y + 30) // set here!
                }})
                .border(.red)
            // .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height) // not necessary
            
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 50) {
                Text("EV Location x: \(Int(evPointLocation.x)) y: \(Int(evPointLocation.y))")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .padding(.top, 20)
                VStack {
                    Text("Image Frame: width: \(Int(imageFrame.width)) - height: \(Int(imageFrame.height))")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(Color.black)
                    Text("Origin: x \(Int(imageFrame.origin.x)) - y \(Int(imageFrame.origin.y))")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(Color.black)
                }
            }
            
            EVPointView()
                .position(evPointLocation)
                .gesture(DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        let rect = CGRect(origin: imageFrame.origin, size: CGSize(width: imageFrame.width, height: imageFrame.height))
                        if rect.contains(value.location ) {
                            self.evPointLocation = value.location
                        }
                    })
        } //: ZStack
        .coordinateSpace(name: "myCoord") // HERE YOU SET YOUR COORD SPACE !!!
        .background(.black)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I need the GeometryReader because I will need it in the future to set the image size based on user device. 

But after trying this solution with more time, it doesn't work when the ContentView is inside a NavigationView. It seems like it is getting the wrong frame size.